# How to open Design screen for winform in Rider IDE?

Tags: c#, winforms, rider

I am trying to develop a Windows Form application in Rider IDE but unable to open the Design screen (in Visual Studio double click on Form1.cs).

[image]

How to open it on Rider IDE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rider doesn't support that functionality,
[Source](https://rider-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000129764-Windows-Forms-Can-I-view-them-).
If you have visual studio installed on same machine you could use it to design your forms since placing components on your form just generates C# code in other portion of partial class that is your form.

Answer (score 1):

A Windows Forms designer was added to Rider in version [2019.1](https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2019/04/30/rider-2019-1-arrived/) (see image below).

To open it, you just double click the form in the Solution Explorer exactly as you would in Visual Studio.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think it's help you. > [link](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Navigating_to_Action.html?_ga=2.88049169.842656576.1579254691-1951734004.1578071574)
If not, after this restart IDE and compile project.
After this in IDE > right click on form.cs > open designer(shift + f7)